# EAV Attributes Install script - VS - eav_attribute_label table (For Select Attributes)

Tags: product-attribute, magmi, eav, install-script

This question is very specific, I'm currently creating **Select** (*Dropdown*) product attributes with **string keys** (*not int*) in Magento using installation scripts without any issue using both custom source model and eav/entity_attribute_source_table with the help of the getDefaultEntities() function.

The problem I'm having now is that I need the "**eav_attribute_label**" table to get populated with the data as if I would have manually created an attribute from adminhtml interface.

1. Using custom model, no table are filled at all
2. Using eav/entity_attribute_source_table only eav_attribute_option and eav_attribute_option_value get filled but not eav_attribute_label.
3. What other solution would fill all three table?

The main reason I need this is because some extensions and/or third parties softwares require these tables to be filled to recognized data coming from these attribute and can't read source model. An exemple would be importing product using Magmi, it works perfectly fine importing values for almost any manually created from adminhtml values but as soon as the three tables are not filled it is unable to find the attribute values. There is lots of people complaining about this and I think the solution is not to customize extensions or Magmi to work with custom attributes but to create the attributes the default Magento way, and therefore make the attribute compatible with any extension requesting it. Unfortunately even after browsing the core installer files and *of course* Google I haven't found a way to replicate with the install script how Magento does to fill these tables. I know I could manually inject the MySQL database but it is not recommended and I'm looking for a built in function.

**There is a part of my code to help you better understand my position:**

app/code/local/NameSpace/Module/sql/module_setup/**mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
$installer = $this;

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$setup->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product', 'Default', 'Attribute Group', 4);

$installer->installEntities();

$installer->endSetup();
```

app/code/local/NameSpace/Module/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/**Setup.php**

```
class NameSpace_Module_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{

    public function getDefaultEntities()
    {

        return array(
          'catalog_product' => array(
            'entity_model'                => 'catalog/product',
            'attribute_model'             => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
            'table'                       => 'catalog/product',
            'additional_attribute_table'  => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
            'entity_attribute_collection' => 'catalog/product_attribute_collection',
            'attributes'        => array(
                'attribute_code' => array(
                    'group'             => 'Attribute Group',
                    'sort_order'        => 0,
                    'label'             => 'Attribute Name',
                    'type'              => 'varchar',
                    'input'             => 'select',
                    'default'           => '',
                    'class'             => '',
                    'backend'           => '',
                    'frontend'          => '',
                    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
                    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible'           => true,
                    'required'          => false,
                    'user_defined'      => true,
                    'searchable'        => false,
                    'filterable'        => false,
                    'comparable'        => false,
                    'visible_on_front'  => false,
                    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                    'unique'            => false,
                    'option'    => array (
                        'values' => array (
                            'stringkey'    => 'Value Name',
                            'stringkey'    => 'Value Name'
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
          ),
        );   
    }
}
```

Any help and suggestion will be greatly appreciated!